Git - preventing out of sync issues between develop and master branch when multiple feature branches are worked on
I recently had an issue with my remote branch of Master being out of sync with Develop. I deleted my develop branch and created a new one by pulling in Master.
When my team is working on a feature branch we pull directly from master, when ready to test we then push these changes to develop and if all is good we push from develop to master. This works great in a perfect world but the issue is when the team is working on multiple features at the same time. Lets say I'm working on feature branch A. I push my changes to develop from feature branch A, testing looks good and I'm ready to push to master. The issue is I can't push from develop to Master as develop is full of bugs/issues from other branches.
In this scenario is it ok if I push the same branch (feature branch A) directly to master? As I already have pushed this same exact branch to develop. I did do this recently and when I made a compare from Master > Develop it showed a difference of 1 commit but 0 file changes. Is that ok? Should I have done something else? What is the best practice in this scenario?

This is the problem with these waypoint branches. In my opinion it is, yes, better to merge from that A branch into master. Of course what the solution or best practice is depends on the framework or philosophy, which is not mentioned here. Read man gitworkflows under “Graduation”. That’s for the Git project but they use long-lived branches in a useful way.
